# Evaluar código c# desde una cadena

Tags: c#

Necesito evaluar unas cadenas de texto como código c# en tiempo de ejecución. Por ejemplo algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dic.Add("a", 123);
dic.Add("b", 456);
dic.Add("c", 789);

var contador = Evaluar("dic.Keys.Count"); //3
var datoB = Evaluar("dic.First(p => p.Key == \"b\").Value"); // 456
```

Estas cadenas luego las podría obtener de una base de datos para poder realizar diferentes operaciones a partir del objeto "dic". Obviamente requiero evaluar un objeto mucho más complejo, pero la idea es la misma.

Muchas gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: Se puede [compilar al vuelo](https://www.west-wind.com/presentations/DynamicCode/DynamicCode.htm) aunque no exactamente como tu deseas.

Comment: Roslyn permite evaluar código: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias a todos. Creo que, en efecto, Roslyn me ayuda a lo que necesito.

Answer (score -1):

Primero deberías declarar la variable dic de manera general, o podrías pasarlo como parámetro a tu método Evaluar junto con al string a evaluar. 
En tu método evaluar pones un switch para saber que se tiene que evaluar y lo retornas como objeto.
Algo así:

static Dictionary dic = new Dictionary();

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dic.Add("a", 123);
        dic.Add("b", 456);
        dic.Add("c", 789);

        var contador = Evaluar("dic.Keys.Count"); //3
        var datoB = Evaluar("dic.First(p => p.Key == \"b\").Value"); // 456
        Console.WriteLine(contador);
        Console.WriteLine(datoB);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static object Evaluar(string opcion)
    {
        object result = null;

        switch (opcion)
        {
            case "dic.Keys.Count":
                result = dic.Keys.Count;
                break;
            case "dic.First(p => p.Key == \"b\").Value":
                result = dic.First(p => p.Key == "b").Value;
                break;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la sugerencia, el problema es que las "cadenas" deben poder ser definidas en una base de datos (desde un portal), entonces si requiero agregar una nueva tendría que agregarla también en el switch de este método, lo cual quita lo "dinámico".